# I am trying to make TicTacToe Application

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make TicTacToe Application, I have already implemented the "player Vs player" part but I am having trouble with implementing the player Vs computer. I have a function called playgame. For update_player I am doing manually and for update computer, I am doing it using random, and I think this is causing the issue as I am checking if my boardStatus is already filled, if it's filled I am calling my function again. I read online that all the calculation should be done on thread, I tried implementing it but I think I am doing it wrong. Please Help!

Here's my code for reference:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_computer.*
import java.util.*


class ComputerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var player = true
    var turnCount = 0
    var boardStatus = Array(3) { IntArray(3) }
    lateinit var board: Array<Array<Button>>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_computer)
        board = arrayOf(
            arrayOf(First, Second, Third),
            arrayOf(Fourth, Fifth, Sixth),
            arrayOf(Seventh, Eighth, Ninth)
        )
        playGame() 
    }
    private fun playGame(){
        Status.text = "Player's Turn"
        for (i in 0..2) {
            var flag: Boolean = false
            for (j in 0..2) {
                if (player) {
                    Status.text = "Player's Turn"
                    update_player(player)
                    Thread.sleep(2000)
                    player = false
                    turnCount++
                    checkWinner()
                    if (turnCount == 9) {
                        Status.text = "Game Draw"
                        flag = true;
                    }

                } else {
                    Status.text = "Computer's Turn"
                    update_computer(player)
                    Thread.sleep(2000)
                    player = true
                    turnCount++
                    checkWinner()
                    if (turnCount == 9){
                        Status.text = "Game Draw"
                        flag = true
                    }

                }

            }
            if(flag == true)
                break
        }
        changeBoard()
        resetBtn.setOnClickListener{
            player = true;
            turnCount = 0
            changeBoard()
        }
    }

    private fun update_player(player:Boolean){

        for(i in board){
            for(button in i){
                button.setOnClickListener{
                    when(it.id){
                        R.id.First->{
                            updateBoardStatus(row = 0, column = 0,player)
                        }
                        R.id.Second->{
                            updateBoardStatus(row = 0, column = 1,player)
                        }
                        R.id.Third->{
                            updateBoardStatus(row = 0, column = 2,player)
                        }
                        R.id.Fourth->{
                            updateBoardStatus(row = 1, column = 0,player)
                        }
                        R.id.Fifth->{
                            updateBoardStatus(row = 1, column = 1,player)
                        }
                        R.id.Sixth->{
                            updateBoardStatus(row = 1, column = 2,player)
                        }
                        R.id.Seventh->{
                            updateBoardStatus(row = 2, column = 0,player)
                        }
                        R.id.Eighth->{
                            updateBoardStatus(row = 2, column = 1,player)
                        }
                        R.id.Ninth->{
                            updateBoardStatus(row = 2, column = 2,player)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private fun update_computer(player:Boolean){

         var row:Int = 0
         var column:Int = 0
       Thread {
            row = (0..2).random()
            column = (0..2).random()
       }.start()

            if(boardStatus[row][column] == 0 || boardStatus[row][column]==1)
               update_computer(player)
            else
                updateBoardStatus(row, column, player)



    }

    private fun updateBoardStatus(row:Int, column:Int, player:Boolean){
        val text = if (player) "X" else "0"
        val value = if (player) 1 else 0
        board[row][column].apply {
            isEnabled = false
            setText(text)
        }
        boardStatus[row][column] = value
    }

    private fun checkWinner(){
        //Horizontal --- rows
        for (i in 0..2) {
            if (boardStatus[i][0] == boardStatus[i][1] && boardStatus[i][0] == boardStatus[i][2]) {
                if (boardStatus[i][0] == 1) {
                    result("Player Won!!")
                    break
                } else if (boardStatus[i][0] == 0) {
                    result("Computer Won")
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        //Vertical --- columns
        for (i in 0..2) {
            if (boardStatus[0][i] == boardStatus[1][i] && boardStatus[0][i] == boardStatus[2][i]) {
                if (boardStatus[0][i] == 1) {
                    result("Player Won!!")
                    break
                } else if (boardStatus[0][i] == 0) {
                    result("Computer Won!!")
                    break
                }
            }
        }



        //First diagonal
        if (boardStatus[0][0] == boardStatus[1][1] && boardStatus[0][0] == boardStatus[2][2]) {
            if (boardStatus[0][0] == 1) {
                result("Player Won!!")
            } else if (boardStatus[0][0] == 0) {
                result("Computer won!!")
            }
        }

        //Second diagonal
        if (boardStatus[0][2] == boardStatus[1][1] && boardStatus[0][2] == boardStatus[2][0]) {
            if (boardStatus[0][2] == 1) {
                result("Player Won!!")
            } else if (boardStatus[0][2] == 0) {
                result("Computer Won!!")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun result(res:String){
        Status.text = res
        if(res.contains("Won")){
            disableButton()
        }
        else{

        }
    }

    private fun disableButton(){
        for(i in board){
            for(button in i){
                button.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }

    private fun changeBoard(){
        for (i in 0..2) {
            for (j in 0..2) {
                boardStatus[i][j] = -1
            }
        }

        for (i in board) {
            for (button in i) {
                button.isEnabled = true
                button.text = ""

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of these calls to `Thread.sleep()`? They will freeze the UI and risk showing an ANR error message to the user, so you should not do that. Unrelated comment: you most definitely don't need to worry about multithreading for a tic tac toe game.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Even if I remove that it my UI still freezes, I think the problem is with update_computer function when I am trying to generate random numbers otherwise I can't see the issue. Can you please help!

Comment: I don't see why it would freeze the UI, but it won't do what you're trying to do. It's spinning up a thread to do that work in the background. You've created a race condition where x and y possibly won't be set yet by the time you pass them  to the other functions. You should remove absolutely all references to anything Thread-related in your code. Nothing that you're doing is going to take a long time to calculate. Think about a complicated game with fancy graphics and how much it does 30 or 60 times a second. If your game is less complicated than one of those, you don't need multi-threading!

Comment: Oh, I see the fundamental strategy you're using doesn't make sense. I'll write an answer.

Comment: @Tenfour04 After removing all the thread I am only able to play player's turn but computer isn't playing it's turn.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to put the whole sequence of actions of the game in a function that is called once and then expects player button-presses to happen internally. Button listeners will fire some time in the future, after the function already returns. You need to think in terms of there being a function that is called each time a button is pressed to do the next stage of the game.

To fix this:

Remove the `playGame()` function.

Remove the `player` parameter from `update_player()` since it's always true. And change the function name to `initializeButtons`. Call it once in `onCreate()`. You only have to add listeners to the buttons one time and they will work repeatedly.

Also remove the `player` parameter from `update_computer()` for the same reason as above. And remove the threading so it looks like:

```
private fun update_computer() {
    val row = (0..2).random()
    val column = (0..2).random()
    if (boardStatus[row][column] == 0 || boardStatus[row][column] == 1)
        update_computer()
    else
        updateBoardStatus(row, column, player)
}
```

Then at the end of the `updateBoardStatus` function call `checkWinner()`. `checkWinner()` should return a Boolean, so in `updateBoardStatus()`, if no win condition has been found and `player` is true, it should call `update_computer()`.

So what you have now instead of trying to run the game from one function, you set up button listeners one time to start the game. When a button is pressed, it takes the player turn, which then triggers `updateBoardStatus`, which then triggers the computer turn, which then triggers `updateBoardStatus` again, and then does nothing if no one won. All of that happens synchronously/instantly on the main thread, so now the game is back to waiting for a button press from the user to repeat the sequence of events.

Also, the `status` text view has limited usefulness. Since the computer takes its turns instantly, it's not possible to ever see the words "Computer's turn". If you want to do that, you'll have to create an artificial delay, so you would have to disable all the buttons and then do something like call `postRunnable({ startPlayerTurn() }, 1000L)`, where the `startPlayerTurn()` re-enables the appropriate buttons and makes it say, "Player turn" again.

Comment: This is just general guidelines to get you thinking about it the right way. There are probably more bugs to be found in there but I don't have time to write the whole app for you. For one thing, your `boardStatus` should be in a ViewModel so the game doesn't start over completely if the screen rotates.